# How can I test angularJs controller which return an object

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I try to write a test for one of my controller method which return an object but I don't know which should be the expected result in this case. Can someone help me please?

This is my Controller function

```
$scope.initdatatable = function (ajaxUri, columns) {
                    return {

                        "bProcessing": true,
                        "bServerSide": true,
                        "bJQueryUI": false,
                        "sAjaxSource": ajaxUri,
                        "stateSave": true,
                        "stateSaveCallback": function (settings, data) {
                                 return $rootScope.userData;
                        },
                      "language": {
                            "aria": {
                                "sortAscending": ": activate to sort column ascending",
                                "sortDescending": ": activate to sort column descending"
                            },
                            "emptyTable": "No data available in table",
                            "info": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
                            "infoEmpty": "No entries found",
                            "infoFiltered": "(filtered1 from _MAX_ total entries)",
                            "lengthMenu": "Show _MENU_ entries",
                            "search": "",
                            "zeroRecords": "No matching records found"
                        },
                        "order": [
                            [0, 'asc']
                        ],
                        "lengthMenu": [
                            [20, 50, 100],
                            [20, 50, 100] // change per page values here
                        ],

                        "pageLength": 20,
                        "dom": "<'row' <'col-md-12'T>><'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-12'f>r><'table-scrollable't><'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>", // horizobtal scrollable datatable                                                                                                       ol-sm-12'f>r><'table-scrollable't><'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>"
                    };
```

This is my test case :

```
 it('should initdatatable ',function(){
        $scope.initdatatable();
        expect($scope.bProcessing).toBe(true);
     });
```

but I get as result

> Expected undefined to be true.

Comment: Well, your function doesn't set $scope.bProcessing to true. It returns an object that has a field bProcessing which is true.

Comment: You are right @JBNizet but have you any idea how can I test if my object field `bProcessing` is true?

Comment: `var result = $scope.initdatatable(); expect(result.bProcessing).toBe(true);`

Comment: Thank you sooo much @JB Nizet you it works for me.